# Angular service Worker and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, angular-service-worker

MY angular service worker works wonderful locally and it asks me to refresh my screen as it's supposed to. However, if I deploy my application to S3 which is being served up through Route53 and CloudFront so that it can be used as an HTTPS site. It doesn't work

All my CloudFront Settings default the only thing I've added were invalidations adding my index.html and my service-worker to that list.

CDN:

[image: CDN]

Invalidation:

[image: Invalidation]